# PayPal PDT stopped returning to my website

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-pdt

I've been using PayPal Website Payments Standard for many years - I use both IPN and PDT. Recently I discovered that although IPN is still working fine, the customer is no longer returned to my website at the end of a purchase, so the PDT is not called, and the customer never makes it back to my website (this is new - it has been working fine for years).

I do have Auto Return turned on in my PayPal settings. The page it's supposed to go to exists and is working fine. That landing page is never hit in the logs.

This is broken on the live PayPal site and in the PayPal Sandbox.  The page that I land on says "Your payment was completed. To continue shopping, please return to the merchant."  There is no "Return to Merchant" button. The URL for this page is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?flow=1-P&ulReturn=true&token=2GX255130M045604B&mfid=1540506852194_f375a853a7234&useraction=commit&country.x=US&locale.x=en_US&country.x=US&locale.x=en_US#/checkout/genericError?code=PAYMENT_ALREADY_DONE.  This page used to automatically redirect back to my website.

On a related note (not sure if it's the same problem) the "Continue Shopping" button on the PayPal Cart page doesn't work anymore either.  I am sending the URL for the page in a hidden field of the form I send to PayPal for my Add to Cart button as shopping_url, but when I click "Continue Shopping" it appears to be taking me Back (like a browser back) to the page that submitted the form rather than going to the page I specified in shopping_url.  Again, this has worked for years, but now is no longer working.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I got a response today from PayPal Tech Support.  They said this is a known issue and they will let me know when they have fixed it.

Comment: PayPal has now fixed this issue.  Also, I learned that the "Continue Shopping" problem was a different one. Because my buttons are hosted buttons, I had to use the PayPal edit button UI (Step 3 advanced options) and insert 'shopping_url='<my url>' to make the Continue Shopping button work again. PayPal is now ignoring any values sent via the form for hosted buttons.

Answer (score 1):

[not an answer, but I can't post comments]

This broke a few months ago for us ([Paypal button "return" parameter doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51387630/paypal-button-return-parameter-doesnt-seem-to-work)). In the new checkout flow, Paypal ignores the "return" value passed in the button/form, it redirects the customer to the URL configured in website settings (https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website).

I'm not sure if Paypal developers read this forum for bug reports or not, but this definitely looks like a regression.

Comment: It's good to know that PayPal is ignoring the values sent in the form - thanks for sharing that. Unfortunately the correct return page is also set in my website settings, but that's not working for me either. I opened a ticket with PayPal but haven't heard back yet.

Comment: Thanks for the "businessmanage" link - it had to be there somewhere! Saved me!